# Changing coordinate systems of asc file in Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, coordinates, esri-ascii-raster

I am working with asc files and what I need to do is do change the coordinates from Lambert Equal Area to WGS 84.

I’ve tried a few things (xarray, rasterio, GeoPandas...) but nothing seems to work out. I can’t find any helpful example code for my situation, so does anyone have a tip or link for me?

Sorry for the lack of detail!

Since I have not much experience with GIS I don't know what my best attempt was but so far I have tried to convert using this function with rasterio:

```
def reproject_et(inpath, outpath, new_crs):
    dst_crs = new_crs # CRS for web meractor 
    # open initial data
    with rio.open(inpath,crs='EPSG:102014') as src:
        transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
            src.crs, dst_crs, src.width, src.height, *src.bounds)
        kwargs = src.meta.copy()
        kwargs.update({
            'crs': dst_crs,
            'transform': transform,
            'width': width,
            'height': height
        })
        #print(src.meta)
    # create new tif file
        with rio.open(outpath, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
            for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
                reproject(
                    source=rio.band(src, i),
                    destination=rio.band(dst, i),
                    src_transform=src.transform,
                    src_crs=src.crs,
                    dst_transform=transform,
                    dst_crs=dst_crs,
                    resampling=Resampling.nearest)
```

But I don't think that the reprojection worked. Also when I load the file using `rasterio.open` or `gdal.open` and want to print the initial projection I only get 'None'. I also wanted to try GeoPandas but I get an error when trying to load the asc file!

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please limit your questions to one per topic, otherwise they're hard to answer - and the correct answer is hard to find later on. Also, please include relevant code and error message, as well as prior research, attempts and ideas. Thank you.

Comment: We can't tell what went wrong with attempts that are not detailed. Please [Edit] your question to specify your best attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: always try to provide a zip to a sample of what you're trying to do. Try sending a file archive for us to check out what you're trying and what's breaking.